# One to One to Many EF 6.1.3 get count of many in first 'One' relation lazy loaded

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relational-database

I have a one-to-one-to-many relation in a database I didn't make. I've created the DbContext and the Entities for EF 6.1.3:

```
public class A{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public class B{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public class MyDb : DbContext {
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }
}
```

When I get an A:

```
var a = MyDb.As.FirstOrDefault();
```

And do a count on the C collection of the related B (one to one with the A), the Cs collection is empty:

```
var countCs = a.B.Cs.Count; // This is 0
```

While when I do:

```
var b = MyDb.Bs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.AId == a.Id);
var countCs = b.Cs.Count; // This is the correct value
```

How should I build the relation with data annotiations or with FluentApi to get the lazy loading working from A to Cs?

Comment: First thing to is always: check the executed SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
public class A
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
public class MyDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
        public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
                .HasKey(p => p.AId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.B)
                .WithRequired(p => p.A);
            modelBuilder.Entity<C>()
                .HasRequired(p => p.B)
                .WithMany(p => p.Cs)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.BId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added this to my DbContext. Still the count returns 0. Any other ideas?